# bash/shell how to access to memory/buffer to use what I have echoed before

Tags: bash, sh

I have 2 scripts.
one of the lines at the **first** script is

```
"...
./second_script >> $outputfile
..."
```

The **second** script has a lot of calculation and variables. Now at some point I need to use everything I echoed to the **outputfile**:

```
".....
echo $var1
echo $var2
.....
echo $var3
echo What I have echoed | script3
..."
```

What I have echoed - its $var1 $var2 $var3

How can I do it?

Its a big code, so I cannot do something like that for each line

```
echo $var
echo $var >> tmp
```

I cannot do that also cause I have like 2000 $var($var isn't realy a variable, its more like "grep......")

```
echo $var1 $var2 | script3
```

I need somehow get an access to what in memory/buffer to what I echoed.

Comment: It's hard to figure what you're saying.  Do you want to use the variables defined in script2 in script1?

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to parse `$outputfile`

Comment: Ill try to be more clear. After second_script, outputfile will be created. Now in script2 when I arrive to the line with script3, I echoed a lot of stuff. I need all the stuff I echoed till now in script2 piped to script3. How can I do it without changing to much the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{ echo $var1
  echo $var2
  echo $var3
  ...
} | script3
```

Comment: thats not good cause the echos are scatterd at the script.
I dont want to change the code too much, the second script is too big.

Comment: Then just pipe one script into the other: `script2 | script3`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the beginning of your script:

```
exec > >( tee tmp )
```

Everything you write to standard output will also be added to the file "tmp".

---

Using `/bin/sh`, you'll need to simulate the process. No guarantees that this is correct:

```
# Create a named pipe to act as a buffer, and set up a background job
# that continuously duplicates whatever is written to it to both
# a regular file and standard output
mkfifo buffer
( tail -f buffer | tee tmp ) &

# Now, redirect standard output to the named pipe
exec > buffer
```

Comment: I think it might work, but now I get syntax error.
"syntax error near unexpected token '<'".

I wrote your line at the beginning of script2, and i removed tmp at the end of script2. I also did echo tmp | script3

Comment: `<`? Make sure your script is actually being run as a `bash` script, as process substitution (`>( ... )`) is not a POSIX feature.

Comment: #!/bin/sh. its not really bash, its sh.
did I put it in the right place in the code?

Comment: `/bin/sh` does not support process substitution. You would have to run the script with `bash` instead.

Comment: I cant change it from sh to bash.. is there maybe other syntax or something?

Comment: it doesn't work..(I put the 3 lines at the beginnig of the code)

Comment: I tried something like that. exec > tmp5. but at the end when I want to print it out -> cat tmp5(for $outputfile), it doesn't print it. I think the problem is that it print back to tmp5(cause its now get all the output from stdout). how can I change it back to stdout?